# Elastic Search hangs and causes a freeze on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, java

I am trying to run ElasticSearch-0.19-4 on Ubuntu 11 64bit VM. The problem is that it when i run it,it freezes the system which resumes about 30 seconds. Probably crashing at the backend. My runtime enviroment is as under. Prev i had openjdk6 but then i tried with openjdk-1.7 but to no avail.

```
root@elastica:/home/madmin/elasticsearch-0.19.4/bin# dpkg --get-selections|grep jdk
openjdk-6-jdk                   deinstall
openjdk-6-jre                   deinstall
openjdk-6-jre-headless              deinstall
openjdk-7-jre-headless              install
openjdk-7-jre-lib                       install

root@elastica:/home/madmin/elasticsearch-0.19.4/bin# java -version
java version "1.7.0_147-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.0) (7~b147-2.0-0ubuntu0.11.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to update to latest 0.19.9 version? Some important issues have been fixed.

Comment: well it turned out that .jar libs were not correct. I built them myself and it was solved